# Heroku App crashes with H10 code possible because of mongo db url

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

Is this still possible to use Parse Server on Heroku.
I found out that the most of videos and articles were created 2-7 years ago.

I deployed my forked code from https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example to the Heroku app,

but when I try to reach my [Heroku app url](https://parse-server-example-heroku-5799b138a415.herokuapp.com) it trows error:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=parse-server-example-heroku-5799b138a415.herokuapp.com request_id=6887bbaa-b870-4fb1-81a4-d23aebeff877 fwd="79.117.228.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I investigated solution from this [link](https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl) but nothing helps.

Espicaily I did not find Procfile in the repo.

I noticed that old videos say that we need to use mLab MongoDB which is not available anymore, I've tried another one which was suggested `ObjectRocket for MongoDB`

But it did not resolved the problem probably because of key/value setup:

```
export const config = {
  databaseURI:
    process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
```

As I understand we probably need to use ObjectRocket and setup it correctly.

this is the full config:

```
export const config = {
  databaseURI:
    process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://parse-server-example-heroku-5799b138a415.herokuapp.com/', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['Posts', 'Comments'], // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong environment variable.

ObjectRocket for MongoDB doesn't set `MONGODB_URI`, but rather [`ORMONGO_URL` and `ORMONGO_RS_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ormongo#provisioning-the-add-on), with the latter being preferred.

Update your configuration accordingly:

```js
export const config = {
  databaseURI:
    process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.ORMONGO_RS_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
```

You can probably remove the `DATABASE_URI` option as well. The ObjectRocket variable will be used on Heroku, and you're presumably using the literal for local development; I'm not sure why the `DATABASE_URI` would be necessary.

```js
export const config = {
  databaseURI:
    process.env.ORMONGO_RS_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
```

Comment: thanks in this case DATABASE_URI no needed, I did like you proposal and deployed new code, but the app still won't run and I have the same log issue, do I need to put  database password somewhere, also I noticed that by default ObjectRocket create instance but not create database, I've tried to create on but it did not help. I've checked config vars on setting and they're mongodb://lon5-c14-1.mongo.objectrockt which was automatically assigned, but I don't know if I need to modify it. or where establish connection to database, thanks

Comment: Please edit more context into the error logs in your question. In particular, I'd like to see what gets printed above the `code=H10 desc="App crashed"` line.

Comment: Thank you! I have another one question maybe more specified and related to this one, it is contains the log and all steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926598/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku-cant-connect-mongodb